# Python method won't initiate

Tags: python-3.x, methods

There is no error showing up but the method doesn't work/initiate. I coded `name_find` to search and print the matching strings in the list `names`, however it doesn't print `matches`.

```
name = [
"dashlane",
"mega",
"killer"
]

#Finding names                                                                                              
class find_Name:

    def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name 


#Finding names in list `name`
                                                                                                             
    def name_find(self):
    matches = [match for match in ln if looking_name in match]
    print(matches)


#Inputting the name to find
    
looking_name = input(": ")
ln = find_Name(looking_name)
ln.name_find
```

Comment: Please put all code in a single coherent code block with proper indentation.

Comment: You call methods by putting parenthesis `()` after its name.

Comment: This is my first time using stackoverflow and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I fix these bugs:

- `[match for match in ln if looking_name in match]`, `ln` is your `find_name` class instance,which can't use after `in`, and can't use it when you write class code.
- `ln.name_find` without `()` to call the method

code:

```
#Finding names                                                                                              
class find_Name:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name 


#Finding names in list `name`
                                                                                                             
    def name_find(self,looking_name):
        matches = [match for match in self.name if looking_name in match]
        print(matches)


#Inputting the name to find
    
name = ["dashlane","mega","killer"]
ln = find_Name(name)
looking_name = input(": ")
ln.name_find(looking_name)
```

result:

```
: mega
['mega']
```